# UIPickerView property of another view not displaying even though I've set datasource, delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, interface-builder, uipickerview

I have a `FilterViewController` that acts as a datasource and delegate for a `UIPickerView` I am displaying in a modal view. My `pickerView` is a property of a `FilterActionSheetView` which is in turn a property of a `FilterActionSheetViewController`.

My code is as follows:

```
    UIPickerView *pickerView = self.customASVC.actionSheetView.pickerView;

    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;

    NSLog(@"%@,pickerView);

    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:self.customASVC.view];
    [self.customASVC viewWillAppear:NO];
```

However the result of the `NSLog()` is always `nil` and thus my picker view never shows up, even as an empty picker view. My impression was that as long as I set the `pickerView`'s datasource and delegate appropriately it would show up.

Comment: Either customASVC or actionSheetView or pickerView is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

customASVC or actionSheetView or pickerView (the pickerView that's a property of actionSheetView) is nil. Break that chain up into separate statements and see where you're getting a nil value.

Comment: You're right - `actionSheetView` logs as `(null)`. So, the way I connect these guys is I add a `FilterSheetViewController` in my `FilterViewController` nib, connect it, and specify a custom nib file. In that custom nib file I have a `view` that is transparent and `actionSheetView` which is a `FilterSheetView` property of the VC that is nil

Comment: And I know that the nib is loading because it is rendering some buttons and image views, just not my picker view.

Comment: Why are you adding a FilterSheetViewController in the FilterSheetViewController's nib? That doesn't even make sense. Is `actionSheetView` an instance of FilterSheetViewController? If not, what does FilterSheetViewController have to do with anything? What class is customASVC?

Comment: And why are you trying to create a new UIPickerView based on some other picker view in some other class 4 degrees of Kevin Bacon away from self? You have to provide all of the data for the pickerView in self anyways, so why not just alloc/init a new UIPickerView and drop that chained dot notation ugliness?

Comment: I figured out that after I called it once (in the `NSLog` for example) it worked the next time. Not sure why. Followed @jmstone's advice and refactored it out of the dot notation chain.